# save view state with cursor adapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter, savestate

I have a listview in which i load data with cursor adapter and content provider, the data is loading and scrolling correctly except of background, the view background is not able to save its state....so i had tried my every approach to save the background of view but i failed...any help would be greatly appreciated.

package papuu.items;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import papu.R;
import papu.db.Order;

public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
    // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);
        vView.setTag(new ViewHolder(vView));
        // no need to bind data here. you do in later
        return vView;// **EDITED:**need to return the view
    }

    // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
    // such as setting the text on a TextView.
    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        Order cPerson = new Order(cursor);

//here the row background is not able to save its background state, as i scroll the row background gets shuffled
        if (cPerson.status == 3)
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8FCC85"));  //Green Accepted
        else if (cPerson.status == 0)
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B0BEC5"));    //gray Picked Up

        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        vh.restaurentName.setText(cPerson.restaurantName);
        vh.address.setText(cPerson.customerAddress);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'-'mm'-'dd'T'hh':'mm':'SS'Z'");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date;
        int mins = 0;
        int hrs = 0;
        try {
            date = df.parse(cPerson.pickupTime);

            hrs = (int) ((date.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            mins = (int) ((date.getTime() / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Log.e(cPerson.status + "",mins+"");
        vh.pickupTime.setText(hrs + ":" + mins);
        vh.price.setText("Tk. " + cPerson.status);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView restaurentName;
        TextView address;
        TextView pickupTime;
        TextView price;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            restaurentName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurent_name);
            address = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
            pickupTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_pickuptime);
            price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (cPerson.status == 3)...` you need definitive `"else"` branch

Comment: first thanks, i don't know what you want to convey, status can have only three state 3(green), 0(grey) and 1(default, so no need for it)....would you explain your point more??

Comment: if you have "if" you need an "else" where you set the "default" background color for status "1"

Comment: It worked but i am unable to understand it as if the condition is not met then why background gets shuffled.

Comment: because views are reused

Comment: ok thanks for your help @pskink

Comment: @Arjun sharma  - It doesn't get "shuffled", the views are RECYCLED in Android, so "row" variable that you get as bindView parameter is some other view that WAS COLORED BEFORE. So the solution to your problem is just adding else for "all other conditions".